# Order ranking column algorithm

Tags: database, algorithm

For example I have a column called `rank` in table `questions`. It described the order of these questions. Let's describe that column with a list: [1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 9998, 9999, 10000].

Now the user see question has `rank = 10000` so important and wanna drag that question and drop to `rank = 4`. The list now will be [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, ... , 9999, 100000, 4] so that I can get and order by this column and there is a new order.

In other words, we will make [1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 9998, 9999, 10000] ->  [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, ..., 9999, 10000, 4]

Is there any way to do this without loop and plus 1 every element from [4, 9999] ?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Depends on the underlying structure of your list. Is it random access? if so, you can do swap(questions,index_to_swap_1,index_to_swap_1) If it is linked list, there is no way unless you have two preassigned pointers pointing to the previous elements on the list.